# Chrome app window only

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

Is it possible to launch a Chrome app without having the Chrome Browser appear?

In other words can the browser run in the background and launch a chrome application?

Comment: [Starting Google Chrome in application mode](https://superuser.com/a/1616926/1039759)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if the app creates its own window then just run it from the Chrome [app launcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/launcher) or make the shortcuts on desktop / startmenu / taskbar: open `chrome://apps/` page (it can be opened from the new tab page), right-click the app, click `Create shortcuts`.

To run the app using command line use the app ID (to get it first create a shortcut as described above and simply copy the command line from the shortcut's parameters, or you can copy it from the webstore page of the app), here's a Windows command line using `start` which automatically finds the installed Chrome executable:

```
start chrome --app-id=pelimflkpjiicnajdjcmekpioacmahkh
```

P.S. The app must be installed in the browser.

Comment: Any examples how this is done?    I've tested the Calculator example but Chrome browser is launched.   This examples: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples

Comment: I closed down chrome and from the terminal typed this:   chrome.exe --load-and-launch-app=D:\Temp\chrome-app-samples\samples\calculator

it starts the chrome browser and the calculator. I only want the calculator to run. How ?

Comment: This is not what I wrote in the answer. Your question is different, I've added the command line method too.

Comment: I tried the steps above but I still get the chrome browser window open. Should it work on specific chrome versions ?

Comment: Works on Chromium 31, Chrome Stable 46 and dev-channel 48, so I'd say this pretty much covers everything in between.

Comment: I got one application working. To be able to run an app without starting the chrome browser. Do I have to have Chrome App Launcher  installed ?

Comment: Chrome App Launcher is an integral part of the browser and can't be uninstalled. What do you mean by `installed`?

Comment: The thing is that I'm experimenting with Chromium and I guess Chrome App Launcher is not part of Chromium. How can I solve it using Chromium ?

Comment: It works on Chromium 31 portable here. Just in case if it wasn't clear from the answer: the app must be installed in the browser. BTW [Chromium source code](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/browser/ui/webui/app_launcher_page_ui.cc&sq=package:chromium).

Comment: Then to another question. Is it possible to install the app in the browser from command line ?

Comment: Indeed, this is another question :-) and it should asked as a separate question. I think this is not possible but maybe someone knows better.